# How to update UITableCell image using protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have used KVO in UITableViewCell for listening to change in imagename variable change inside UIViewController but it crashes while setting imagename and sending notification since table cell deallocated.

How can I achieve it using Protocol/delegates?

Comment: From cellForRowAtIndex method or somewhere else ?

Comment: can you please add some code snippet.